# acumatica how to bulk delete projects

Tags: acumatica

We have about 200 projects that have been uploaded with the incorrect project code into Acumatica ERP.  Is it possible to bulk delete all the projects at once, rather than deleting one by one? The problem with deleting projects is that it's time consuming since you have to first change the status of each task to "cancelled" or "planned" before deleting the project record.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good way to do bulk operations in Acumatica is by using integration services. The typical use case people have in mind with import scenarios is importing records, but you can use it to update existing records, and delete them.

For your particular request, I'm not 100% sure you can do both operations from the same scenario so I would suggest the following:

1. Create an Excel file which contains the list of projects and project tasks that needs to be be set to "Cancelled" status. You can use generic inquiries to create this quickly and export the inquiry results to Excel.
2. Create an import scenario that will locate the project/task and change status to Cancelled and save the project
3. Create another Excel file which contains the project codes only, without the task. You can also use a generic inquiry for that
4. Create an import scenario that will find the project, and call  on the project.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a Generic Inquiry with option 'Enable Mass Record Deletion'.

1. Go to the Generic Inquiry form (SM208000)
2. Create new Generic Inquiry
3. Add row to grid 'Tables' with table name PX.Objects.PM.PMProject
4. Add conditions PMProject.NonProject=false, PMProject.IsTemplate=false,
   PMProject.BaseType='P', Status='D' (In Planning)
5. Specify Entry screen = Organization->Projects->Work Area->Manage->Projects Check
6. Enable Mass record Deletion

Answer (score -1):

EDIT: Misunderstood as **customization project**

Un-Publish all projects first

Below tables should do the trick. Please try on a test DB first.

```
Delete  from CustObject
Delete from CustProject
Delete from CustomizationDesign
Delete from CustomizationPublished
```

Comment: The question is about Projects, not customization projects. Furthermore, I would never advise to delete straight from database :)

Comment: oh, its projects. Sorry for the misunderstanding.